# Rearrange geom_point by size

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-point

I have a variable (-coef-) that is just regression coefficient values. I am hoping to arrange all the -var- (variables of different models) in my plot based on the size of their respective -coef- values. I have tried various solutions using reorder() (such as https://www.rpubs.com/dvdunne/reorder_ggplot_barchart_axis) but they all seem geared towards geom_bar or geom_col and haven't worked with geom_point/geom_errorbar.

```
ggplot(d, aes(x = var, y = coef,
              ymin = ci_lower, ymax = ci_upper,
              color = var)) +
  geom_point(size = 2) +
  geom_errorbar(width = .5,
                size = 1) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_minimal()
```

EDIT: Some example data

```
d <- structure(list(var = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", 
"i", "j"), coef = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.35, 0.46, 0.64, 0.54, 0.13, 
0.87, 0.41), ci_lower = c(0.05, 0.15, 0.25, 0.3, 0.41, 0.59, 
0.49, 0.08, 0.82, 0.36), ci_upper = c(0.15, 0.25, 0.35, 0.4, 
0.51, 0.69, 0.59, 0.18, 0.92, 0.46)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(var = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), coef = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), ci_lower = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), ci_upper = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))
```

Comment: It's hard to help without some example data. Please edit your post to include the output of `dput(d)`.

Comment: @jdobres sorry, I'm working with restricted data on a restricted server so it isn't easy (or allowed!) for me to share, but I generated some similarly structured data and added here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `arrange` your data by "coef" and then recode "var" with `factor(ordered = T)`. Note that ggplot will switch to a different color scale for ordered factors, so I also specify `scale_color_hue()` in the plot:

```
d %>% 
  arrange(coef) %>% 
  mutate(var = factor(var, unique(var), ordered = T)) %>% 
ggplot(., aes(x = var, y = coef,
              ymin = ci_lower, ymax = ci_upper,
              color = var)) +
  geom_point(size = 2) +
  geom_errorbar(width = .5,
                size = 1) +
  scale_color_hue() +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks--I had tried arranging coef before but without converting -var- into a factor. Works perfect.